# Laravel 5.2 Unable to find the socket transport "TLS" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP

Tags: php, email, laravel, laravel-5, reset-password

I use default reset password in laravel 5.2
When I click reset password button , add to password_resets table but show me this error

> Swift_TransportException in StreamBuffer.php line 265:
>   Connection could not be established with host smtp.mail.yahoo.com   [Unable to find the socket transport "SSL" - did you forget to enable it when you configured PHP? #2005938298]

this is my .env file

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mail.yahoo.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=myacount@yahoo.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=mypassword
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=SSL
```

and my mail.php file

```
'driver' => env('MAIL_DRIVER', 'smpt'),
'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mail.yahoo.com'),
'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 465),
'from' => ['address' => 'myacount@yahoo.com', 'name' => 'reset password'],
'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'SSL'),
'username' => env('myacount@yahoo.com'),
'password' => env('mypassword'),
'sendmail' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
```

I add in php.ini `extension=php_openssl.dll` and reset apache.
I copy ssleay32.dll and libeay32.dll in system32.
I use wamp.